# Сделать скриншот когда флаг WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE включен

Tags: java, android, kotlin, remote

Как запретить запись видео с экрана Android приложения, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE не подходит он блокирует делать скриншоты, скриншоты необходимы.

Comment: если необходимы делайте screen shot программным путем

Comment: а оно запустится автоматически или нужно на клик Button'а реализовать